# При отрисовке элементов интерфейса в цикле теряется один элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

коллеги! Пишу небольшую программу по сбору данных с счетчиков, сейчас делаю интерфейс. Проблема в том при создании данного класса

```
class RemoteSiteTab(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, boreholes, site, **kw):
        super().__init__(root, **kw)
        self.boreholes = boreholes
        self.site = site
        self.frames = [SensorFrame(self, text=borehole_name) for borehole_name in self.boreholes[site]]
        self.tab_columns = 0
        self.tab_row = 0
        for sensor_frame in self.frames:
            if self.tab_columns != 5:
                sensor_frame.grid(row=self.tab_row, column=self.tab_columns, padx=10, pady=5)
                self.tab_columns += 1
            else:
                self.tab_columns = 0
                self.tab_row += 1
                sensor_frame.grid(row=self.tab_row, column=self.tab_columns, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Должно создаться 12 фреймов, однако по какой-то неизвестной мне причине - создается 11. Один элемент теряется. Я подозреваю, что проблема связана с счетчиками внутри цикла. [Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/Vankalif/monitoring) . Если что-то оформил не правильно, заранее извиняюсь.

Comment: Обнаружил, что элемент позицию элемента 6 в сетке, перезаписывает элемент 7, когда начинается блок else для элемента 6 переменная tab_columns = 0, после этого берется элемент 7 и для него tab_columns тоже равняется 0, получается перезапись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать проще:

```
        self.column_count = 5

        for i, sensor_frame in enumerate(self.frames):
            tab_row, tab_columns = divmod(i, self.column_count)
            sensor_frame.grid(row=tab_row, column=tab_columns, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Полностью:

```
class RemoteSiteTab(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, boreholes, site, **kw):
        super().__init__(root, **kw)
        self.boreholes = boreholes
        self.site = site
        self.frames = [SensorFrame(self, text=borehole_name) for borehole_name in self.boreholes[site]]
        self.column_count = 5

        for i, sensor_frame in enumerate(self.frames):
            tab_row, tab_columns = divmod(i, self.column_count)
            sensor_frame.grid(row=tab_row, column=tab_columns, padx=10, pady=5)
```

---

**PS.**

Тот `divmod` соответствует делению нацело и получению остатка от деления:

```
tab_row = i // self.column_count
tab_columns = i % self.column_count
```

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет. Использовал Ваш вариант.

Comment: @N.Turshiev, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае при переходе в блок else после добавления 6 элемента нужно увеличить переменную снова на 1

```
            else:
                self.tab_columns = 0
                self.tab_row += 1
                sensor_frame.grid(row=self.tab_row, column=self.tab_columns, padx=10, pady=5)
                self.tab_columns += 1
```